# Add/Update contents of other branches into master

Tags: git, github, git-branch, git-merge, branching-and-merging

I have got 4 teams adding their code in 4 dedicated branches in GIT (branchTeam1,branchTeam2,branchTeam3,branchTeam4).
Once they finalize their code and pass validation, we have to add/update everything in branch master.
I tried to perform merge in GIT UI, but it completely replaced master with branchTeam1. I want master to be updated/added, not replaced.

Please suggest a way to do the same either in GIT UI or command-line.

Comment: What do you mean by "replaced"? Merge will apply the changes made by the branch you want to master, if your master did not suffer any changes since the creation of your branch, it will become the same as your branch after merge. Isn't this what is happening? Check more at [here](https://git-scm.com/book/en/v2/Git-Branching-Basic-Branching-and-Merging).

Answer (score 0):

You can merge the branches to master one by one. After every merge you need to carefully resolve all the conflicts before proceeding with the merging of new branch.

In given case, follow these steps:

1. Ensure all branches are updated in their remote repository
2. `git checkout master`
3. `git merge branchTeam1`
4. Resolve all code conflicts
5. git add --all
6. git commit (This will give you an auto commit message like `Merge remote-tracking branch 'origin/branchTeam1' into master`)
7. git push origin master

Repeat steps 3-7 for branchTeam2, branchTeam3, branchTeam4.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The best way to solve this issue by creating a pull request to the master.

Let everybody work on the different feature, once they are done, they can commit the changes and push it to the remote. Then create pull request to the master.

Before creating a pull request to the master they should take a pull from the master.

Entire flow explained below.

> git checkout -b in_app_purchase

then commit your changes locally and push the local changes to remote

```
git add -A
git commit -m 'Feature:InApp purchase added'
git push -u origin in_app_purchase
```

before creating the pull update your branch with master

```
git pull origin master
```

Then create a pull request. This is the easy way !!